# Read/write to specific memory address (very simple memtest) -> Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, testing, memory, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have created a simple memtest program.

However, when I try to run it (with sudo, of course) it crashes at the following line:

main -> test_all -> test_running -> for (j=0; j<=memsize; j++) p[j]=1-value; // (first assignment operation)

And it does not specify the error. I am thinking about two possibilities:

**1)** Wrong memory range, should choose another one (which?)

**2)** Something wrong with my code (where?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MEM_start 0xFD002000
#define MEM_end 0xFDFFFFFF
#define MEM_size 16769023

int test_running(int value) {
    int i, j;
    int flag=0;
    int *p = (int *)MEM_start;
    int memsize = (int)MEM_size;
    for (i=0; i<=memsize; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<=memsize; j++) p[j]=1-value;
        p[i]=value;
        if (p[i]!=value) { printf("Error at address: %p\n", &p[i]); flag++; }
        for (j=0; j<=memsize; j++) {
            if ((j!=i)&&(p[j]==value)) {
                printf("Error at address: %p\n", &p[j]);
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int test_chess() {
        int i;
        int flag=0;
        int *p = (int *)MEM_start;
        int memsize = (int)MEM_size;
        for (i=0; i<=memsize; i++) p[i]=i%2;
        for (i=0; i<=memsize; i++) if (p[i]!=i%2) { printf("Error at address: %p\n", &p[i]); flag++; }
        for (i=0; i<=memsize; i++) p[i]=(i+1)%2;
        for (i=0; i<=memsize; i++) if (p[i]!=(i+1)%2) { printf("Error at address: %p\n", &p[i]); flag++; }
        return flag;
    }

int test_random() {
    int i, j;
    int flag=0;
    int *p = (int *)MEM_start;
    int memsize = (int)MEM_size;
    int buffer[32];
    int buffer_size=32;
    for (i=0; i<=memsize; i=i+buffer_size) {
        for (j=0; j<=buffer_size; j++) buffer[j]=(0==(rand()%2));
        for (j=0; j<=buffer_size; j++) p[i+j]=buffer[j];
        for (j=0; j<=buffer_size; j++) if (p[i+j]!=buffer[i]) { printf("Error at address: %p\n", &p[i+j]); flag++; }
    }
    return flag;
}

int test_all() {
    int test=0;
    int flag;
    flag=test_running(1);
    if (flag) { test++; printf("Running 1 - FAIL\n"); }
    else printf("Running 1 - SUCCESS\n");
    flag=test_running(0);
    if (flag) { test++; printf("Running 0 - FAIL"); }
    else printf("Running 0 - SUCCESS\n");
    flag=test_chess();
    if (flag) { test++; printf("Chess - FAIL\n"); }
    else printf("Chess - SUCCESS\n");
    flag=test_chess();
    if (flag) { test++; printf("Random - FAIL\n"); }
    else printf("Random - SUCCESS\n");
    if (test!=0) { printf("SOME TESTS FAILED: %i", test); return 1; }
    else { printf("ALL TESTS PASSED!!!"); return 0; }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    test_all();
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: the following links are quite helpful:
1) [FixUnix: writing to device at a known physical address](http://fixunix.com/embedded/261343-writing-device-known-physical-address.html)

2) [DesignSomething: a simple code to read/write a physical address from userspace](http://designsomething.org/leopardboard/f/23/t/77.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address `0xFD002000`  that you are trying to read/write to is not mapped in your process. Its not valid for your process to access it. That is why you are getting segmentation fault on first access to it.

Also, note that (in mainstream desktop OSes like Windows, linux, Mac) the addresses in your processes are virtual addresses and not actual physical addresses. More at [Virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)

Comment: @JakeBadlands: If you want to map at a specific virtual address, see mmap() . Mapping a specific physical address is not possible from user space, you'd need to modify the kernel.

Comment: @JakeBadlands - Why do you wish to achieve this? Let the wife (AKA OS) get on with those problems,

Comment: @EdHeal I am making a simple memtest program, so in case of test failure, it should detect which physical address fails.

Comment: @JakeBadlands, getting to physical address is not that straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc` or `new` - that depends on if you are using C or C++.

Also avoid casts - they usually imply you are doing something wrong.